# <router-outlet></router-outlet> generated content is visible only for a helf a second of less

Tags: angular, routes, web-component

I have my front-end layer of app. It is build on angular 17 and components are standalone. I tried some routing and it didn't work out.

My app.component.html contains only this:

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

And my app.routes.ts contains this:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CenterBarComponent } from './center-bar/center-bar.component';
import { BottomBarComponent } from './bottom-bar/bottom-bar.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FrontPageComponent } from './front-page/front-page.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: FrontPageComponent },
    { path: "bb", component: BottomBarComponent },
  ];
```

After going in the link: http://localhost:4200/bb (path to BottomBarComponent) it will properly show the html file of that component, but only for like less than half a second of something like that - it vanishes fast. If that html file (app.component.html) would contain anything else than router-outet then after the BottomBarComponent vanishes it would only show the content left in the file without the router-outlet content.

This is the code of my app.config.ts:

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(), provideHttpClient(withFetch())]
};
```

Why is that BottomBarComponent vanishing so fast and not staying even though I am not changing the link (I stay at http://localhost:4200/bb)?

It works like that as well with the FrontPageComponent.

So to sum up - the content shown by router-outlet is visible only for less than half a second or something like that and then vanishes. Why is it acting this way?

Comment: Do you have stackblitz example for this?

Comment: @PavanJadda no, I don't

Comment: It should work as expected. I need to see Stackblitz to figure of the issue exactly

Comment: @PavanJadda so you need me to post my app to stackblitz and give you the link?

Comment: Not the whole app, just the part that can reproduce the error. Use the template https://stackblitz-starters-dgcm3d.stackblitz.io